# Weird symbol shadowing from GraphicsRasterInformationPatch` when loading NCAlgebra`

Tags: symbols, contexts

When doing

```mathematica
PacletInstall[
  "https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/blob/master/NCAlgebra-6.0.3.paclet?\
raw=true"];
Needs["NCOptions`"]
(*SetOptions[NCOptions,SmallCapSymbolsNonCommutative->False];*)
Needs["NCAlgebra`"]
```

I get the following shadowing warnings:

```mathematica
Global`g: Symbol g appears in multiple contexts {Global`,GraphicsRasterInformationPatch`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
<<similar warnings for h, r, w>>
NCAlgebra::SmallCapSymbolsNonCommutative: All lower cap single letter symbols (e.g. a,b,c,...) were set as noncommutative.
```

Note that the last line is expected behavior of the [`` NCAlgebra` ``](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC)  package, which just sets an attribute to Global lower-letter symbols.
I am trying to google what the `` GraphicsRasterInformationPatch` ``  context is, but didn't find anything relavent.
There seems indeed to be a symbol called `` Image`GraphicsRasterInformationPatch ``,
which did not give me more clues to the mystery.
The context includes the following symbols:

```mathematica
Names["GraphicsRasterInformationPatch`*"]
(*
{"array", "bstyle", "bstyle$", "dbstyle", "dbstyle$", "g", "gopts", 
"h", "h$", "info", "info$", "is", "isr", "isr$", "is$", "pr", "pr$", 
"r", "range", "ropts", "size", "w", "w$"}
*)
```

I however have still no idea why I have this context introduced to my session.

I tried restarting the kernel, but the problem is persistent. It does not mess with some basic calculation I'm trying to do right now, but I'm unsure whether some packages or paclets I have are misbehaving. Is there some way to get closer to this?

Comment: Using ```Remove["GraphicsRasterInformationPatch`*"]``` after loading ```NCOptions` ``` indeed removes the symbols, but I still don't know why they are introduced in the first place.

Comment: By discussion with @E. Chan-López as well as leaving this post here for a few days, I've been generally sure this is merely due to the implementation of the `NC` package. The paclet may have been introduced somehow internally, and I'll try to make a PR if I've got a clue.

Comment: NCAlgebra does not make use of any other paclet.

Comment: I only encountered this when interacting with `NCAlgebra` though. Shall I make this into an issue at the repo?

Comment: I suspect this may arise from some context/name mishandling, maybe on WRI's part?

Comment: Its this package that is setting g in the global context as pointed out below. We do that as a convenience in NCAlgebra and offer a key to turn it off, just in case it gets in your way. If anything, I would make it an issue with the developers of that particular paclet.

Comment: I would like to mention that no such paclet/package seems to exist, based on the search results I'm getting; `GraphicsRasterInformationPatch` seems to merely be an internal symbol used by Mathematica. I suspect it has been mishandled and made into a context, and I am _not_ accusing NCAlgebra for doing that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently, and it was resolved by uninstalling the Paclet:

```
PacletUninstall["GraphicsRasterInformationPatch"]
```

You can use Remove, but it will only solve it temporarily, that is, when you reboot the kernel again you will have to use Remove again.

That Paclet caused something strange in my version (13.3), since it was placed as a context for the unprotected symbols `g`, `h`, `r`, `w`. I already verified that the same thing happens in version 14.

Comment: I'm using v14 too; verifying this is a paclet is another piece to the puzzle. What is this paclet for, where did it come from, and how was it installed on our machines though? I'll try doing some further investigation

Comment: @Gravifer I know we have something in common, since I also used the non-commutative algebra package. I assume that it is very likely that Paclet came included in the package folder and was installed by default. Not only that, but I haven't seen it anywhere else.